# How to Add a Child View to the Center of a ViewGroup

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

I have created a custom circular ProgressBar following [this](https://medium.com/@sreekumar_av/how-to-create-your-own-progressbar-in-android-511419293158#.svu3uakyp). Now I want to add this progress bar to the center of my layout. The problem is that it is added to the top left of the activity, no matter how I change LayoutParams attributes passed to addView(). The code is as follows:

```
// Create a progress bar to display while the list loads
            mProgressBar = new DualProgressView(getApplicationContext());

            ViewGroup root = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 500, Gravity.CENTER);
            root.addView(mProgressBar,params);
```

Comment: Just use it in xml with center align. or if you want to add it at runtime Then just assign LayoutParams as per parent layout.

Comment: The `android.R.id.content` `ViewGroup` is normally a `FrameLayout`, not a `LinearLayout`. You shouldn't really rely on that, though. Add your `DualProgressView` to a `ViewGroup` you've declared in your layout, so you know exactly what it is, and which `LayoutParams` to use. Btw, you should use the `Activity` for the `Context` you're instantiating that `DualProgressView` with, instead of `getApplicationContext()`, so it gets the right theme and styles applied.

Comment: @ADM Now I used      `LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(root.getLayoutParams());` and it spans the whole width and does not align to the center vertically. I don't like it.

Comment: Agree with you Mike. @JasonStack  I think the problem is in your DualProgressView . Post your DualProgressView.java

Comment: [DualProgressView.java](https://github.com/pollux-/DualProgressBar/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/custom/progress/DualProgressView.java)

Comment: `ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(root.getLayoutParams());
            root.addView(progressBar, params);` Also does NOT work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make your progress bar height and width as wrap_content, or, say 40sp in xml.
2. set attribute **android:layout_gravity="center"** to your ProgressBar within your LinearLayout.

or programmatically, try this:

```js
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(thisActivity);

ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
ll.addView(progressBar);

layout.addView(ll,params);
```

Comment: This centers the progress bar, but it is still too big. How can I set its size programmatically?

Comment: You can also specify the progressbar size but doing this: ll.addVIew(progressBar, 30, 30)